SQL - When using a WHEN THEN ELSE statement, how can I remove the ELSE rows?
I have 3 conditions that I am looking for approval dates, all accounted for in WHEN THEN statements.  I use the ELSE at the end of this because I know there are some that have not been approved yet and name them 'N/A' instead of the date.  When I export this list I only want the 3 conditions of the approval dates and not those N/A ones.  How can I remove those ELSE results or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks for any help.
CASE
WHEN
(SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for QA Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%') LIKE '%[0-9]%'
THEN (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for QA Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%')
WHEN
(SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%') LIKE '%[0-9]%'
THEN (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%')
WHEN
(SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%In Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%') LIKE '%[0-9]%'
THEN (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%In Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%')
ELSE 'N/A'
END AS "Approval Date"

I am new to SQL so I haven't tried much so far.

Please read How To Create A Good Example

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And don't forget to add a tag fpr the dbms used, there are several product specific functions used above.

I strongly suspect you don't want all those subqueries. What does the rest of your query look like? Also please name which database platform you're using.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Rehashing my knowledge in SQL-
I hope this helps!! replace "YourTable" with yours
If you want to exclude the ‘N/A’ results from your output, you can add a WHERE clause to your SQL query to filter out these results. Here’s how you can modify your query:
  SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN
                (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for QA Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%') LIKE '%[0-9]%'
            THEN (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for QA Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%')
            WHEN
                (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%') LIKE '%[0-9]%'
            THEN (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%Ready for Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%')
            WHEN
                (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%In Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%') LIKE '%[0-9]%'
            THEN (SELECT Substring(cy.cy_user_07,Charindex('Final Approved',cy.cy_user_07)+25,10) FROM cycle CY WHERE cy.cy_cycle_id = c.cy_cycle_id AND cy.cy_user_07 LIKE '%In Approval</font></b> to <b><font color = "green">Final Approved%')
            ELSE 'N/A'
        END AS "Approval Date"
    FROM YourTable
) AS T
WHERE T."Approval Date" != 'N/A'

